# ¿ Cómo crear un programa que interprete ciertos comandos expresados en lenguaje natural?

Tags: java, android

Quiero poner un editText y que el usuario escriba operaciones matemáticas y que la App le responda, tipo:

¿ Cuanto es 5+6 ? Y la máquina diga , 11.

O por ejemplo,

Dime cual es el resultado de 5+6 . Y que le vuelva a decir , 11.

¿ Cómo puedo poner para que me lea cualquier cadena y me interprete lo que estoy diciendo ? Tengo que poner una base de datos con mil millones de frases posibles dependiendo de la forma que me planteen la pregunta o hay alguna forma para que da igual como me pregunte, yo lo entienda y le responda?

Comment: Podrías editar el título de tu pregunta con algo mas claro, por favor. El título debería tener relación directa con el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Ya me has contestado miso, me la has aclarado, gracias

Comment: Si sólo te interesan operaciones matemáticas, podrías tomar del texto sólo los números y los operadores, para luego calcularlo... Pero depende del alance del proyecto.

Comment: Mirate también https://github.com/ptnplanet/Java-Naive-Bayes-Classifier podrias determinar cuando quieres sumar, restar, multiplicar, despues solo deberias separar los numeros para procesarlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La única manera de que puedas interpretar cualquier tipo de `input` de parte del usuario hoy en día es utilizando AI (Inteligencia Artificial). Un proyecto en github que trata del tema en android es [moondroid/Chatbot](https://github.com/moondroid/ChatBot)

El asunto aquí es que este campo no es nada sencillo. Ya tienes ejemplos de chat bots creadas por Google que no terminan de cuadrar del todo.

Claramente como lo que tu quieres es manejar operaciones matemáticas simples, los requerimientos se contraen y será mas facil de implementar algo así.

Esto tambien va muy ligado al idioma en específico, lo cual complica las cosas, por ejemplo dos `inputs` que tendrian el mismo significado:

`Si tengo 5 manzanas y como 4, cuantos me quedan?`

`Si comí 4 manzanas de las 5 que tenía, cuantas tengo ahora?`

Son la misma pregunta, pero con los números en diferentes posiciones, así que no es algo meramente de detectar posiciones en el input y aplicar la operación.

Así que si quieres un aplicativo que responda de forma natural, los chatbots con una AI como backend es el camino a seguir.

### otro ejemplo

[Mathbot_for_hipchat](https://github.com/hanks/Mathbot_for_hipchat)

Comment: mirare lo de inteligencia artificial que es lo que busco principalmente, pero vienen ya hechos por Google? Pero no terminan de cuadrar?

Comment: Lo digo en el sentido de que, no consiguen interpretar el lenguaje humano a un nivel que parezca natural. Debido principalmente que en cualquier idioma, hay muchos modismos, regionalismos. Mucha gente directamente escribe mal o no sabe expresarse, etc.

Comment: Sí, es algo difícil, habría que usar un corrector como hace Siri por ejemplo para adaptar. Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres ir mas allá y entender el concepto de aprendizaje artificial, sugiero que revises artículos relacionados a redes neuronales.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

si aún sigues interesado en alternativas, puedes usar  Microsoft Bot Framework (https://dev.botframework.com), wit.ai, api.ai o algún otro sistema de bots de los que están saliendo como setas :) De los que he probado, así por encima, el más sencillo es quizá el de MS.

Ellos harán el trabajo de identificar intenciones y entidades (después de un pequeño entrenamiento) y te devolverán un json con la información que obtengan. Con ella tú ya haces lo que debas.

Answer (score 0):

Si la operación a realizar la indica escribiéndola como en el ejemplo (5+6) solo debes filtrar el input en busca de la operación y parsearla.
De esta manera, con un input como: "Jander clander 2+3 agromenawer" obtendrías solo el "2+3".
El problema es si el input tienen mas de una operación y/o negaciones por ejemplo "Hazme la operación 2+3 pero no la 4+5" en estos casos requieres una IA.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, puedes utilizar una estructura llamada red neural recurrente con esta puedes hacer cosas de aprendizaje de lenguaje natural(chatbots, traductores de lenguajes, resumidores de textos etc ..) gracias a la arquitectura de estas estructuras se pueden procesar caracteres.
Hay CIENTOS de Frameworks de aprendizaje profundo que te servirian, pero lo q te recomiendo es usar [TensorFlow para Android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/), este ejemplo de  [Chatbot en Tensorlfow](https://github.com/nicolas-ivanov/tf_seq2seq_chatbot) te puede servir de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que te reconozca el lenguaje natural, lo mas recomendable hacerlo con PLN (Procesamiento del lenguaje natural), ahora, hay varias librerías en distintos lenguajes para trabajar el PLN, yo actualmente uso Freeling 3.1 para java http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/node/1.